# Any reason not to retag [multiple-definition] to [multiple-definition-error]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I just came across a question tagged with both the [multiple-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition) and [multiple-definition-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition-error) tags.  The tags seem to be redundant — one might be tempted to say there's a multiple definition error while they're both around.

- 109 questions tagged [multiple-definition-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition-error).
- 21 questions tagged [multiple-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition).
- 7 questions tagged with both.
- There's a wiki entry for [multiple-definition-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition-error).
- There's no wiki entry for [multiple-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition)

Is there any good reason not to tag those questions currently tagged [multiple-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition) with [multiple-definition-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition-error) instead?

The net result will be to burninate or otherwise destroy the [multiple-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition) tag.  I don't see any particular need to involve moderators or The Team in the process; 21 questions are easily retagged by a manual process once there's some minimal consensus that it should be done.

Comment: Who knew the phrase "multiple definition" would itself have multiple definitions? (That is, who is to say that it would necessarily refer to a specific type of error? Surely it means something completely legitimate in a different context...)

Comment: @BoltClock: I think every one of the remaining [tag:multiple-definition] questions could legitimately be retagged [tag:multiple-definition-error].  I did just remove the tag from [Declare and assign multiple string variables at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374454/declare-and-assign-multiple-string-variables-at-the-same-time), which didn't really seem to warrant the error tag — the problem was a more basic syntax error.

Comment: OK: no-one jumped up and down saying "appalling idea" so I'll eliminate [tag:multiple-definition]. On the one hand, there hasn't been that much viewing activity on the question (so it might be a bit premature); on the other hand, I was sorely tempted to just do it yesterday (my time).  I'm going to succumb to temptation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag [multiple-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-definition) is no longer in use.  One question was for Latex and the tag was removed rather than replaced; the problem was about multiply defining a label, rather than a linking error.  The rest were retagged.

In due course, the system will forget (remove) the tag.  I've not set 'do not use' information in its tag wiki — one reason it was removed is because it didn't have a tag wiki.  The risk of it reappearing in the next 48 hours or so is low.